# How to have multiple field attributes in one column -Syncfusion and Angular

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I am working with Angular and Synfusion. I wonder how to have multiple attributes in one column. The documentation by Synfusion is not really helpful..

```
  <ej-grid id="Grid" #grid [dataSource]="datasource.infos" allowPaging="true" allowFiltering="true" selectionType="single" allowSelection="true"
    [selectionSettings]="selectionMode" (rowSelected)="rowSelected()" (cellSelected)="onCellSelected($event)">
      <e-columns>
          <e-column field="forename"  headerText="Fullname"></e-column>
      </e-columns>
  </ej-grid>
```

In `<e-column field="forname" headerText <e-column field="forename"  headerText="Patient"></e-column>` I also need the surname in this field but I do not know how to do so with Syncfusion. In the column "forname surname" should be displayed with space inbetween

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Query: “**In the column "forname surname" should be displayed with space inbetween**”

From your query, we understand that you need to display two column value in single column. We have achieved your requirement using **column template** feature of ejGrid. Refer the below code example

`<ej-grid #grid  [dataSource]="gridData" allowPaging="true">
    <e-columns>
        <e-column field="EmployeeID" [isPrimaryKey]="true" headerText="ID" textAlign="right" width="90"></e-column>
        <e-column field="TitleOfCourtesy" headerText="TitleOfCourtesy" textAlign="right" width="90"></e-column>
        <e-column headerText="FirstName - LastName" width="150">
            <ng-template e-template let-data>
               <div *ngIf="data.FirstName">
            {{data.FirstName}} - {{data.LastName}}
               </div>
           </ng-template>
        </e-column>
        <e-column field="Title" headerText="Role" textAlign="right" width="80"></e-column>
        <e-column field="Address" headerText="ShipCity" editType="dropdownedit" width="90"></e-column>
        <e-column field="PostalCode" headerText="ShipPostalCode" width="90"></e-column>
    </e-columns>
 </ej-grid>`

Refer the below screenshot for the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMI1b.png)

Refer our help documentation for your reference

https://help.syncfusion.com/angular/grid/columns#column-template

Please let us know if you have any queries.